# AWS Glue: Unable to infer schema while delta load with job bookmarks

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm working on an AWS Glue Job which uses partitioned data in S3 (parquet files) with job bookmarks. I've experienced problems trying to use the job bookmarks feature for a daily delta load.
Here is how I read the data:

```
val push: String = "p_date > '" + start + "' and (attribute=='x' or attribute=='y')"
logger.info("Using pushdown predicate: " + push)
val source = glueContext
      .getCatalogSource(database = "testbase", tableName = "testtable", pushDownPredicate = push,
transformationContext = "source").getDynamicFrame()
```

This is the AWS Glue Generated Input-files.json which is created after using the job bookmarks logic right after the inital full load. No new data should be processed, which seems correctly displayed with the empty "files" parts.

```
[{
        "path": "s3://path/to/bucket/attribute=x",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "path": "s3://path/to/bucket/attribute=y",
        "files": []
    }]
```

However, instead logging that the files were skipped, this is what happens:

```
After final job bookmarks filter, processing 0.00% of 0 files in partition DynamicFramePartition(com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicRecord@7d679e8a,s3://path/to/bucket/attribute=x,1578972694000). 
After final job bookmarks filter, processing 0.00% of 0 files in partition DynamicFramePartition(com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicRecord@7d679e8a,s3://path/to/bucket/attribute=y,1578972694000).
```

I guess now Glue tries to create an empty DynamicFrame which then fails with the following message:

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.wrapper.SparkSqlDecoratorDataSource$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkSqlDecoratorDataSource.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.wrapper.SparkSqlDecoratorDataSource$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkSqlDecoratorDataSource.scala:38)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.wrapper.SparkSqlDecoratorDataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(SparkSqlDecoratorDataSource.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.wrapper.SparkSqlDecoratorDataSource.resolveRelation(SparkSqlDecoratorDataSource.scala:53)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource$$anonfun$getDynamicFrame$8.apply(DataSource.scala:640)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource$$anonfun$getDynamicFrame$8.apply(DataSource.scala:604)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper$$anonfun$executeWithQualifiedScheme$1.apply(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:63)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper$$anonfun$executeWithQualifiedScheme$1.apply(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:63)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper.executeWith(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:57)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper.executeWithQualifiedScheme(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:63)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:603)
```

Have you experienced a similiar behaviour like this with AWS Glue before?
I'm thinking of implementing a "null-check" for the "to-be-created" Dynamicframe to stop the job from failing. Or do you have any AWS native solutions in mind which could ensure the proper functionality of job bookmarks?